# Jenkins to build only modified files when checkout happens from subversion when build is scheduled

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have configured subversion and Jenkins for Microsoft visual basic 6 project. Subversion contains more than 4000 files. Every time the build triggers, Jenkins compiles 4000 files, even if only few files have changed. I have written a batch script to compile visual basic 6 files which will search for `*.vpb` files in every folder. If `*.vpb`, present it will compile files present in that folder

```
@echo off

del "D:\buildfiles\log_file.txt"

for /r "D:\jenkins_setup\workspace\project" %%a in (*.vbp) do (

"C:\Program Files\microsoft visualstudio\vb98\vb6.exe" /make %%a /outdir 
"D:\buildfiles" /out D:error_log.txt

echo %%a >> "D:\buildfiles\log_file.txt"

)
```

pasted this script in jenkins.

If files from few folders have changed, I want my script to compile only those files, not all 4000 files which are present in Jenkins workspace. To make this work, what else do I need to add to my script?

Comment: I modified the tags on your question. As I stated in my answer, Jenkins is not the issue. The issue is the compiler (which you admitted). This has nothing to do with TortoiseSVN, SVN, or Jenkins. I tried looking up VB6 command line options, but VB6 hasn't been supported in almost a decade, and it looks like from your command line, you're using a 1998 version of VB6. Maybe retagging the questions will help get someone who knows VB6 to give you an answer.

Comment: @OP: You cannot do this only with a bat file. Not with VB6 compiler. You'll need to build either a vbp to makefile transaltor and use nmake (this is how we do it) or inspect source files last modified times manually and build projects only if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins itself doesn't compile. That process is handed to whatever build software you use. For example, if you have a `C` or `C++` project, Jenkins would probably call `make` and pass to it a *Makefile*. If you have a Java project, Jenkins would call `mvn`, `ant`, or `gradle` with the correct POM or Build script. It would then be up to the individual build system to rebuild *intelligently* if so desired.

In your case, it's how Visual Basic itself is handling your Visual Basic Project files. I believe the build system compiles only those files whose last modification date and time is newer than their corresponding object file's modification date and time.

You should be able to get onto your Jenkins system, go to the workdirectory of that project and actually run the build from the command line and see what happens. Check the file dates. You might also want to set the Jenkins project to do an update only instead of a checkout.

Comment: Jenkins is doing update to its workspace initially than it is calling batch file to compile the files some improvement needed in batch script because this script compiling all files i want only modified files to get  compiled.

Comment: Jenkins is doing update to its workspace initially than it is calling batch file to compile the files some improvement needed in batch script because this script compiling all files i want only modified files to get  compiled. I want to add some svn commands in my script if there are some changes made to the file than it should go for compilation.